# ¿Qué hay de malo con esta función?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, funciones

```
Create function InventarioFinal
(@codigo int)
returns table
as
return (select i.NombreProductos as ProductoComprado, f.CantidadComprada, f.Costo as CostoxUnidad, f.Total, f.Fecha as FechadeCompra, 
e.Nombre as EmpleadoEncargado, s.Nombre as Suplidor, su.IdSucursal from Facturas f inner join Inventario i on f.Producto = I.NombreProductos
inner join Empleados e on f.EmpleadoEncargado=e.IdEmpleados inner join Suplidores s on f.SuplidorProducto = s.IdSuplidor inner join Sucursales su
on f.Sucursal = su.IdSucursal
where s.IdSuplidor = @codigo 
group by i.NombreProductos, f.CantidadComprada, f.Costo, f.Total, f.Fecha, e.Nombre, s.Nombre, su.IdSucursal)
```

La función se crea correctamente, pero al momento de ejecutar el 
`select * from dbo.InventarioFinal (2)` me aparece una tabla vacía.

Comment: el código que estás enviando no corresponde con ningún `IdSuplidor`?

Comment: No se si SQL SERVER es "case sensitive", pero en vez de `I.NombreProductos` debería ser `i.NombreProductos`

Comment: @Ale SQL Server puede ser case sensitive dependiendo de la configuración de la base de datos. Pero si fuera ese el problema, no encontraría el alias de la tabla y lanzaría error

Comment: @Lamak Si corresponde a un IdSuplidor

Comment: @Elizabeth la verdad es que es imposible contestar la pregunta sin ver los datos de la tabla. Puede ser que el `Producto` de la tabla Facturas no corresponde con el `NombreProductos` de la tabla Inventario...o el `EmpleadoEncargado` no corresponde con el `IdEmpleados`...o el `SuplidorProducto` no corresponde con el `IdSuplidor`, etc

Comment: @Lamak que lindo verte dando vueltas por todos lados :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
Create function InventarioFinal
(@codigo int)
RETURNS TABLE (columna1 tipodato, columna2 tipodato...)
as
return (select i.NombreProductos as ProductoComprado, f.CantidadComprada, f.Costo as CostoxUnidad, f.Total, f.Fecha as FechadeCompra, 
e.Nombre as EmpleadoEncargado, s.Nombre as Suplidor, su.IdSucursal from Facturas f inner join Inventario i on f.Producto = I.NombreProductos
inner join Empleados e on f.EmpleadoEncargado=e.IdEmpleados inner join Suplidores s on f.SuplidorProducto = s.IdSuplidor inner join Sucursales su
on f.Sucursal = su.IdSucursal
where s.IdSuplidor = @codigo 
group by i.NombreProductos, f.CantidadComprada, f.Costo, f.Total, f.Fecha, e.Nombre, s.Nombre, su.IdSucursal)
```

columna1 tipodato, columna2 tipodato...: deben ser todas las columnas del resultado de tu consulta y deben coincidir los tipos de datos

creo que con eso deberia de funcionar

Answer (score 0):

esa parte en el return

```
returns @resultado table(cantidad numeric(10,3), --numeric(6,2),
                     descripcion varchar(250),
                     valor numeric(19,3),--int
                     total numeric(19,3), --int,
                     linea int,
                     orden int,
                     hoja  int)
```

y esta al final del la funcion

```
    insert into @resultado(cantidad, descripcion, valor, total, linea, orden, hoja)
    select cantidad, descripcion, valor, total, linea, orden, hoja from @tabla order by orden
return
```